# Normal to have multiple "dovecot/pop3-login"?

Tags: linux, unix

I'm getting multiple instances of dovecot running on my LAMP server, which is in resulting in LFD reporting with constant emails with the following..

```
Time:         Mon Jun 13 05:56:34 2011 -0700
Account:      dovecot
Resource:     Process Time
Exceeded:     19811 > 1800 (seconds)
Executable:   /usr/libexec/dovecot/anvil
Command Line: dovecot/anvil [35 connections]
PID:          1621
Killed:       No
```

Here's a picture of the system processes:

[image]

I've tried restarting LFD and CSF, but neither has fixed the problem.

Comment: Fixed that formatting for ya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Dovecot to provide POP or IMAP access to mail, it is normal to see many `pop3-login` and/or `imap-login` processes.  These handle new client connections, and there will generally be one process for each connecting client.  Some additional information is here:

- http://wiki.dovecot.org/RunningDovecot

Comment: I don't use the client email service at all, and the only time I can think of that any of my websites use the email service is when it sends out emails for user registrations. With that being said, could this possibly be some kind of DoS/BruteForce attack? Shouldn't these multiple processes die off after X time?

Comment: If you don't actually need the client email service, you may want to simply disable dovecot.  Your applications don't need dovecot for sending email.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Dovecot forks for each session.
Limit with: `login_max_processes_count`

If server is facing internet, possible brute-force attempt.
Look at netstat source addresses for surety.

May later be of interest: `max_mail_processes`